# Is there any way to show "open file wizard" in R instead of loading file by read.csv?

Tags: r, rstudio, read.csv

I want to provide an option for user to open whatever file he/she wants just by selecting the csv file. Is there any option in R to do so? Surprisingly I could not find such feature.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Where to you want to provide this option? In R? In Shiny? In your OS file explorer?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I would like to run R script which shows a file open wizard in windows OS explorer to open CSV file, which then would be loaded in dataframe. (something similar to Import Data feature, but done through code)

Comment: Like function `choose.file`?

Comment: Ohh okay. So I can use choose.file to get file name and then open it using read.csv, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unclear of what you need. But my understanding is you need something like this:

```
data_frame = read.csv(file.choose())
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Can't approve for 5 more minutes. Stackoverflow policy. Will do it soon, for sure!